# TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str

Tags: python, exception

I'm a beginner to Python running 2.7.6 on OS X 10.8, with numpy and pyobjc added. Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from Foundation import NSMutableDictionary, NSUserDefaults, NSCFArray, objc
import numpy as np
from copy import copy
import os
import re

domainName = "org.mworks-project.MWClient"

outFile = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~/Desktop','org.Behavior.MWClientSavedVars.plist'))
keyNames = [ 
  'MATLAB client window - selected variables',
  'MATLAB client window - MATLAB .m file',
  'recentPythonScripts' ]

homedir = os.getenv('HOME')

################

def subStr(inStr):
    return re.sub('^%s'%homedir, '$HOME', inStr)

def replaceUserdirWithStr(inObj):
    if type(inObj) == str or type(inObj) == objc.pyobjc_unicode:
        return subStr(inObj)
    elif isinstance(inObj, NSCFArray):
        for i in range(len(inObj)):
            # do this recursively
            inObj[i] = replaceUserdirWithStr(inObj[i])
        return inObj
    else:
        print type(inObj)
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        raise 'Error: Type unknown'
    return 

################

# get client defaults
standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
clientDefs = standardUserDefaults.persistentDomainForName_(domainName)

# copy the fields we need
writeDict = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary()
for k in clientDefs:
  if k in keyNames:
    tVal = clientDefs[k]
    tVal = replaceUserdirWithStr(tVal)
    writeDict[k] = tVal
success = writeDict.writeToFile_atomically_(outFile, 1)
############################################################
```

When trying to run this script but hitting this error:

```
<objective-c class __NSCFArray at 0x7fff7b9ea3c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nameOfTheFileHere.py", line 60, in <module>
    tVal = replaceUserdirWithStr(tVal)
  File "nameOfTheFileHere.py", line 45, in replaceUserdirWithStr
    raise 'Error: Type unknown'
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str
```

I'm stumped. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError:exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497234/typeerrorexceptions-must-be-old-style-classes-or-derived-from-baseexception-no)

Answer (score 6):

the line

```
raise 'Error: Type unknown'
```

is invalid because you're trying to raise a `str` rather than an `Exception`

You want to do something more like:

```
raise TypeError('Type unknown')
```

I assume TypeError only because your message was "Type unknown"

For more info, read the docs about raising exceptions:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Answer (score -2):

Not run your python script using the command ./Script.py instead try as below.

Python Script.py

Regards,